# Strange assertion in Durret's probability book

Tags: probability-theory

In page 27 of the fifth edition of the book *Probability, theory and examples* of Rick Durrett he says something like

> Let $X_n\to X$ a.s. and defines $\bar X_n:=X_n \mathbf{1}_{\{|X_n|\leqslant M\}}$ for some $M$ such that $P(|X|=M)=0$. Then, as $P(|X|=M)=0$, $\bar X_n\to \bar X$ a.s.

I dont follow why the condition $P(|X|=M)=0$ is needed for the almost sure convergence of $\{\bar X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$. It is an error or this condition is really needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary. Let $X_n=M+\frac 1 n$ and $X=M$. Then $X_n \to X$ a.s. and $X_nI_{|X_n| \leq M}=0$ for all $n$ whereas $XI_{|X| \leq M}=M$.

Comment: I see... Very enlightening this example! This happens because $M$ is not an interior point of $[-M,M]$!